# PHP Convert string from ASCII to UTF-8 / WINDOWS-1255

Tags: php, utf-8, ascii, windows-1255

This ASCII letter (MS-DOS Hebrew / CP862):

> €

need to output this (UTF-8/Windows-1255):

> א

Those methods give me no result so far:

```
$string = "€";
echo iconv('CSPC862LATINHEBREW', 'Windows-1255',  $string);
echo iconv('CSPC862LATINHEBREW', 'UTF-8',  $string);
echo iconv('CSPC862LATINHEBREW', 'CP862',  $string);

echo mb_convert_encoding($string, 'UTF-8', 'CSPC862LATINHEBREW');
echo mb_convert_encoding($string, 'Windows-1255', 'CSPC862LATINHEBREW');
echo mb_convert_encoding($string, 'CP862', 'CSPC862LATINHEBREW');
```

Comment: I guess your approach will not work, because the char € in MS-DOS Hebrew / CP862 will be not א in UTF-8/Windows-1255. What is your actual goal? Do you want to "translate" the euro symbol into hebrew?

Comment: i have files in ASCII format and i want to convert them to Hebrew strings in php

Comment: Why do you want it? ASCII is a subset of UTF-8 and Hebrew should by also part of UTF-8.